# How to solve the following integrodifferential equation by generic approach?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, syntax, integral-equations

Consider the following equation:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - p H(t)\frac{\partial f}{\partial p} = \mathcal{I}[p,t], \tag 1
$$
Here, `f = f[p,t]`, with p being momentum and t time, while $H$ and $\mathcal{I}$ are

$$
H(t) = G \sqrt{\int p^{3}f dp},
$$
with $G$ being some constant, and
$$
\mathcal{I}[p,t] = \sum_{i}\int \limits_{p_{2,\text{min}}^{i}}^{p_{2,\text{max}}^{i}}dp_{2}\int \limits_{p_{3,\text{min}}^{i}}^{p_{3,\text{max}}^{i}}dp_{3} \ \text{integrand}^{(i)}
$$
where `integrand` depends on `f` with the various linear combination of momenta p, p2, p3.

In principle, the second summand in the LHS of this equation may be eliminated by the change of variable $p \to \epsilon = \frac{pa}{a_{0}T_{0}}$ ($a_{0} = 1, T_{0} = 0.015$ in units of GeV), where $a$ is defined as
$$
H(t) \equiv \frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial t}
$$
which would also allow the solution to stay within the same domain of the momentum coordinate $\epsilon$ at any moment in time:
$$
\frac{\partial f(\epsilon,t)}{\partial t} = \mathcal{I}[\epsilon,t]
$$
The system of equations represents a small piece of the equations from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290641/how-can-i-solve-unintegrated-boltzmann-equation-fast-and-robustly).

For the initial condition and boundaries, I take

```
t0 = 0.001*1/(6.58*10^-25);
pmin=0;
pmax=5;
fini[p_]=1/(Exp[p/0.015] + 1) + Exp[-30 (p - 0.1)^4];
fboundary[t_] = 0;
```

where `fboundary` is for `p>pmax` and `p<0`.

I wonder how it may be possible to solve this system of equations in Mathematica. The starting point for solving this system is probably the method of lines. However, there is the problem that the integral `I` is two-dimensional, and its discretization will produce hundreds of thousands of terms.

However, for sure, some more or less efficient way to solve the mentioned equation using discretization exists. In the literature, people use matlab, fortran, and python. In 2210.10307, for instance, they use matlab with ode15s solver, discretizing the collision integral by using Simpson's method (50-100 bins); the total time required to solve the differential equation is O(1 day), but this is for the coupled system of three equations of the type of $(1)$ with a much larger function $\mathcal{I}$, and also assuming a very good precision of the order of $10^{-4}$ in quantity $\int p^{3}f dp$ (I do not need it, maybe 10^-3 would be enough). 1512.02205 uses fortran, performing the momentum discretization. Neither of these codes is publicly available.

The integrands, the integration boundaries (6 in total), and the value of the constant `G` are provided below:

```
GF = 1.167*10^-5;
tabintegrands = {2/(15 Pi^3)
     GF^2 p1^(-2) p3^3 (10 (p1 + p2)^2 - 15 (p1 + p2) p3 + 
      6 p3^2) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t]), 
   2/(15 Pi^3)
     GF^2 p1^(-2) p2^3 (10 p1^2 + 5 p1 p2 + 
      p2^2) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t]), 
   2/(15 Pi^3)
     GF^2 p1^(-2) ((p1 + p2)^5 - 10 (p1 + p2)^2 p3^3 + 
      15 (p1 + p2) p3^4 - 
      6 p3^5) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t]), 
   2/(15 Pi^3)
     GF^2 p1^(-2) p3^3 (10 (p1 + p2)^2 - 15 (p1 + p2) p3 + 
      6 p3^2) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t]), 
   2/(15 Pi^3)
     GF^2 p1 (p1^2 + 5 p1 p2 + 
      10 p2^2) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t]), 
   2/(15 Pi^3)
     p1^(-2) ((p1 + p2)^5 - 10 (p1 + p2)^2 p3^3 + 15 (p1 + p2) p3^4 - 
      6 p3^5) (-f[p1, t] f[p2, 
        t] (1 - f[p1 + p2 - p3, t]) (1 - f[p3, t]) + (1 - 
         f[p1, t]) (1 - f[p2, t]) f[p1 + p2 - p3, t] f[p3, t])};
MapThread[(integrand[p1_, p2_, p3_, t_, #1] = #2) &, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6}, tabintegrands}];
pmax = 5;
tabboundaries[p1_, 
   p2_] = {{{0, p1}, {0, p2}}, {{0, p1}, {p2, p1}}, {{0, p1}, {p1, 
     p1 + p2}}, {{p1, pmax}, {0, p1}}, {{p1, pmax}, {p1, p2}}, {{p1, 
     pmax}, {p2, p1 + p2}}};
Gval = Sqrt[(3*6.7*10^-39)/(8*Pi)*(4*Pi)/(2*Pi)^3](**1/(6.58*10^-25)*);
Hintegrand[p_,t_]=Gval*Sqrt[p^3*f[p,t]];
```

The speed of evaluation of the integral I using `fini` is ~0.1 s (`AdaptiveMonteCarlo` method is used):

```
integral[p1_] := 
 Sum[NIntegrate[
   Evaluate[integrand[p1, p2, p3, t, i] /. f[P_, t] :> fini[P]], {p2, 
    tabboundaries[p1, p2][[i]][[1]][[1]], 
    tabboundaries[p1, p2][[i]][[1]][[2]]}, {p3, 
    tabboundaries[p1, p2][[i]][[2]][[1]], 
    tabboundaries[p1, p2][[i]][[2]][[2]]}, 
   Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"], {i, 1, 
   Length[tabboundaries[p1, p2]], 1}]
integral[RandomReal[{10^-5, pmax}]] // AbsoluteTiming
NIntegrate[Evaluate[Hintegrand[p,t]/.{f[p,t]->fini[p]}],{p,0,pmax}]
```

Comment: Is it not enough to solve just one of these numerous variants first? What form does the integral equation take after the transformation `p->k==p a`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : sorry, what do you mean by "one of these numerous variants"?

Comment: Aren't `tabintegrands` several variations of the integrand/integrodifferentialequation?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : excuse me, I have not clarified this, the integral is the sum of the integrals with different integrands and integration domains (already changed the corresponding equation).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann : I have added the form of the equations after the variables replacement.

Comment: how about [Euler wavelets collocation method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25274/using-ndsolve-for-integro-differential-equations)?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Have you had a chance to check how long it takes to calculate the collision integral?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : do you mean using `NIntegrate` for a test function `f`?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Yes, for example for `f=fini`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev : Using AdaptiveMonteCarlo, it is around 0.1 s per given value of `p1`.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Could you add code with computation for this case?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : I have added the integral.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Could you add expression  `H`  in units of GeV as well  to your code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev : I have commented `1/(6.58*10^-25)` in the expression for `Gval` and added it in the expression for `t0val`. Sorry, it was a mistake for the previous formulation: the same factor should have been added to all the integrands.

Comment: @JohnTaylor There is no `t0val`  in your code above. Could you add $H(t) = G \sqrt{\int p^{3}f dp}$ in GeV units to your code? We need this expression to compute `a[t]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev : my bad, I meant `t0`. I have added the integrand `HIntegrand` and the integral to the last line.